# JSF Convert dates for title attribute

Tags: jsf, date, converters

I need to put a date into the title attribute of an image so that it displays when the user puts the mouse over. Problem is I would like to change the date format.

Any ideas?

```
<ice:graphicImage value="bean.image" title="#{bean.date}"/>
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either do it directly in a getter method

```
public String getDate() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.date); 
}
```

or grab JSTL's [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html).

```
<fmt:formatDate value="#{bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="date" />
<ice:graphicImage value="bean.image" title="#{date}"/>
```

(which would not work inside repeating components like `UIData`)

Comment: Hi Balus...really quick question. I add JSTL to the pom and the following to the header: xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" 
I cant get it to work...any ideas what is going wrong? It just doesnt display anything on the title.

Comment: Then it's either inside a repeating component, or the date value isn't available during restore view.

Comment: I cant even get a simple hello world to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373592/how-do-you-use-jstl .Not sure if there something else I have to do to enable the tag library.