# How do you use JSTL?

Tags: jsf, jstl

Trying to use JSTL but have the following problem:

Index.xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
<body>
<c:out value="Hello world!"/>
</body></html>
```

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

OUTPUT SOURCE:

```
        <html id="document:html" lang="en" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"><head><meta content="Rendered by ICEFaces D2D" name="icefaces" />
.....
    <c:out value="Hello world!"></c:out>
....</body></html>
```

As you can see its not processing the c:out but just printing it out as text.

Comment: its not processing the c:out just printing it.

Comment: Here is a tutorial to mixing jstl and jsf (http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/21020). I hope it helps you.

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? JSF 2.x / Facelets ships with limited set of JSTL builtin. Which appserver? Some appservers ships with builtin JSTL. Either might have collided with your loose JSTL file.

Comment: JSF 2.1 with Facelets on Tomcat

Comment: It seems it works if I call the page test.jsp but not test.xhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that:

> The solution is to remove the /jsp from the jstl namespace:
>
> xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"

See this [post](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=229801).

Comment: @BalusC Ah... ok. I'll remove this post soon. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: I undeleted the post, until @DD give it a try and tell us it doesn't work. Then I'll remove it, again. :)  Regards

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with adding 
`xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"` in my xhtml file.

OR

declaring this in my web.xml, and copying the c.tld in /WEB-INF/jsp from my application:

```
<jsp-config> 
        <taglib> 
               <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri> 
               <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jsp/c.tld</taglib-location> 
        </taglib> 
</jsp-config>
```

Warning:
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" throws exception, collected in my h:messages Tag