# Accessing bean methods from JSF 1.2 pages - hook life cycle? hack getters?

Tags: jsf, methods, arguments

I want to do something similar to this (in jsf 1.2):

```
<html> 
...
#{myObject.foreignKey(parentObject.primaryKey)}

<h:inputText value="#{myObject.myProperty}"/>
</html>
```

Or in other words: from the web page I want to set a value in an object when arriving on that page.

while this is easy in JSF 2.0, it seems kinda impossible in JSF 1.2 
Is there a hack / workaround for this?
Define a function which takes as argument an object and a String/integer and work on the returned object?
Overwriting inputText (and all other input fields) and accessing all kind of framework related classes seems dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to JSF implementation, but to the EL implementation. In standard EL implementation prior to [EL 2.2 from Java EE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) you cannot pass method arguments like that. Apart from upgrading to a servletcontainer which supports EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss 6, etc), you can also replace the EL implementation yourself. A commonly used one to achieve the particular requirement is [JBoss-EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html). Download and put [`jboss-el.jar`](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and add the following to the `web.xml`, assuming you're using Mojarra as JSF implementation:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

An alternative is just using [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`<c:set>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html):

```
<html xmlns="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
...
<c:set target="#{myObject}" scope="request" property="foreignKey" value="#{parentObject.primaryKey}" />
```

Note that the Facelets' builtin JSTL libs on `xmlns:c="java.sun.com/jstl/core"` also contains a `c:set`, but this is pretty restricted in functionality. The `xmlns:c="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"` requires a fullworthy JSTL lib which is usually already shipped along with a bit fledged servletcontainer. However, in Apache Tomcat for example, you've got to download and install it yourself. For links and more detail, see [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Comment: I get a pretty frustrating:  <c:set> Attribute 'var' is required error when trying your last approach. Handing over a dummy as var makes it just ignore the target. Maybe we are using a special EL lib or I'm missing something (we are using Spring). I gotta have a look into it tomorrow again I fear.

Comment: my c:set attribute 'var' is required error was resulting from the old JSTL 1.0 xmlns... e.g. xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" instead of xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" ( http://www.jsptutorial.org/content/jstl in german ). 
To the problem: well i couldn't verify that jstl c:set is working, it never called the setter for me with JBoss 4.2.2.  I found heaps of examples for JSP, but not a single one with JSF.

Comment: seems like i'm still stumbling in the dark since i cant get the newer .../jsp/jstl/.. tags working at all. Seems there is a bit of confusion... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373592/how-do-you-use-jstl . I'm as well using xhtml

Comment: i'll accept the answer because balusc rox anyways, even though someone should imho edit the JSTL thing.