# How do I access a non-managed-bean class in JSF page?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am using facelets. I have one class:

```
public class foo{
    public static String foofookoo() {
        return "tookoofoopoo";
    }
}
```

How do I access this on my JSF page because this is a simple POJO not a managed bean?

Comment: That's not a POJO. It's normally a *pure* Javabean with only public non-static getters/setters/c'tors. Aren't you talking about an utility class with only static methods (functions)?

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Why is it not a POJO? I thought POJO and java beans are same? Please clarify, i have a doubt. And ya, i was talking about utility class with static methods. I wanted these static methods to be accessed on page.

Comment: You showed a static non-getter method. This cannot be part of a POJO.

Comment: POJO's don't have to have getters and setters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object. From wikipedia: "Ideally speaking, a POJO is a Java object not bound by any restriction other than those forced by the Java Language Specification."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it is *really* a POJO and that your code example is simply bad; the only way to access it nicely is to make it a property of an existing managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {
    private Pojo pojo;

    public Bean() {
        pojo = new Pojo(); // Create/load it somehow.
    }

    public Pojo getPojo() {
        return pojo;
    }
}
```

Then in the JSF page associated with the managed bean just do:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.pojo.property}" />
```

which roughly translates to `pageContext.findAttribute("bean").getPojo().getProperty()`.

But, if it is on the other hand actually an utility class with static non-getter methods, then your best bet is to wrap it in an EL function. You can find a Facelets-targeted example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378826/facelets-and-jstl-converting-a-date-to-a-string-for-use-in-a-field/2381443#2381443).

Comment: Hi BalusC, i did exactly what it said on the link you pointed, But it's not working. I get tag not found error. What should i do? Here is my taglib.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://laala.com/el/AppDeployment</namespace>
    <function>
        <function-name>getCommonImagePath</function-name>
        <function-class>Common.AppDeployment</function-class>
        <funciton-signature>String getCommonImagePath(java.lang.String)</funciton-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>

Comment: In my web.xml i added :-

 <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/AppDeployment.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

I keep getting configuration null error and tag not found in glassfish admin console. Please help me.

Comment: I get this error to be spccific :
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null

Comment: Hi balusC, i figured it out on my own. It was my silly mistake. Thanks again