# Integrating JSTL With Facelets

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets

I am considering using Facelets and JSTL in the same web project.

Are there any issues in integrating these ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facelets has *cloned* a limited set of "good old" JSTL tags and included in the Facelets library. They are all described [here](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-available-jstl). In other words: not all JSTL tags/functions are supported in Facelets.

If there's any original JSTL tag which you would like to use, but isn't made available by Facelets, then you'll head in another corner for the solution. The jobs which can be done by the JSTL [sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/tld-summary.html) and [xml](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html) taglibs doesn't belong in the view, but rather in the model/business logic. The JSTL [fmt](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) taglib is already covered by JSF's `<f:loadBundle>` and the `<f:formatXXX>` tags. The JSTL [functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib can be as good done with custom EL functions. I've posted an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378826/facelets-and-jstl-converting-a-date-to-a-string-for-use-in-a-field/2381443#2381443).

The problem with JSF and the original JSTL library is that they doesn't run in sync as you would expect from the coding. It's more so that JSTL runs the page from top to bottom first and then hands the generated output over to JSF for further processing. This may lead to unexpected results when using for example `<c:forEach>`.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Sorry to comment on a very old post. But, the link which you have provided - https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-available-jstl doesn't work. Can you please give the latest URL?

Comment: @Vikas: all outdated links have been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the Facelets doc [here](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-available-jstl), JSTL can be integrated in Facelets application. However, some components of the JSTL library must be avoided if possible, such as `<c:set>` for example.

Note that Facelets also provide some replacements for JSTL tag. Thus, you can replace `<c:forEach>` by `<ui:repeat>` tag (read more [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) about these two components).