# JSTL XML in JSF Facelet

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, jstl, facelets

I am trying to create a composite component in JSF Facelets 1.2.8.
The component is supposed to be a table optimised to work with the jquery jstree framework for presenting a table as a directory tree.

The component is supposed to accept an attribute containing a xml value, which represents the structure of the tree.
In Order to prepare the component for the presentation as file tree I want to parse the xml data in the components xhtml file.

For this I want to use the JSTL-XML-Taglibrary but it seems like it cant be found.
This is how my namespace declaration looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:x="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml">
```

The core-tag library can be used but every tag from the xml-library is adopted as plain text into the html source.

I tried following:

- Changing the namespace declarations between jstl 1 and jstl 1.2 (insert additional /jsp/ in path)
- javax.servlet.jstl 1.2 is imported via maven
- I added xercesImpl.jar and xalan.jar in the lib directory of my tomcat installation (v. 7.0.68)

I have no clue why the core-library is working but the xml-library doesn't.
Is there something I am doing wrong? Is it even possible to use JSTL-XML in Facelets?

Thanks in advance
Demli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSTL XML (and SQL) taglibs are considered bad practices and are "officious" deprecated since JSP 2.0 (2003) wherein the MVC approach was strongly preferred and advocated over tight-coupling the controller and the model into the view. Facelets, which was introduced a bit later (2005), has even **no support** for JSTL XML and SQL taglibs at all. Only JSTL core and functions are [supported](https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.3/vdldocs/facelets/index.html).

If you're absolutely positive that you need to massage a XML file into a XHTML file, then better use XSL instead. You can find a kickoff example here: [How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields/3511785#3511785).

#### See also:

- [Integrating JSTL With Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644462/integrating-jstl-with-facelets)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion sounds pretty interesting, but I changed over to using the apache trinidad table instead of a composite component. That way I can apply my xml structure to the TableModel in the backend instead of working with xml values and potentially sensitive data in the frontend (Client).