# ConvertNumber maxFractionDigits bean binding

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

double it.error=1 ,int it.d=2

```
<h:outputText value="#{it.error}">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
</h:outputText>
```

displays 1.00

but

```
<h:outputText value="#{it.error}">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="#{it.d}" minFractionDigits="#{it.d}"/>
</h:outputText>
```

displays 1

Using tomcat 6.0.29 and mojarra 2.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if the `<h:outputText>` is inside a `<h:dataTable>` and thus `#{it}` is not available in the scope when the view is been built (but only when the view is been rendered). The tag handlers like `<f:xxx>` are only created/evaluated when the view is been built.

There are several ways to workaround this problem, all which are outlined in the following answer: [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284)