# o:importConstants variable is not accessible by o:validator

Tags: validation, jsf, constants, omnifaces

I get a null value when I pass a constant obtained with **o:importConstants** to an **o:validator** even when they both seems to be accessible on render time.

```
public class Test {
  public static final String PATTERN = "\\d+";
}
```

The constant value is obtained correctly cos I can print it:

```
<o:importConstants type="Test"/>
Pattern is: #{Test.PATTERN}
<p:password id="password" value="#{password}">
  <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="#{Test.PATTERN}"/>
</p:password>
```

When I check **pattern** variable in **RegexValidator**, it's **null**.

I tried also using f:attribute with a custom validator and checked these posts but without success (BalusC, help! :) :

- [Using validator with a variable attribute in ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682196/using-validator-with-a-variable-attribute-in-uirepeat)
- [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284)

Comment: Which OmniFaces version? This has been fixed since 2.1 and still works for me in 2.3 snapshot.

Comment: I see, omnifaces 1.12, cos we are using old myfaces 2.1.12 and primefaces 3.5. Any idea then?

Comment: All fixes in 2.1 are backported to 1.11, so it should work in 1.11 and newer too. Perhaps there's more into the code? Everything works fine for me when I copypaste the exact snippet into `<h:body><h:form>` of a templateless test file.