# jsf validator bean values in parameter lost

Tags: validation, jsf

```
            <h:dataTable value="#{products.getAllProducts()}"
                         var="product">
                ....

                <h:column rendered="...">
                    <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
                    <h:inputText id="basket-qty" value="#{basket.qty}" rendered="#{product.stock.qty > 0}" >
                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
                        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="#{product.stock.qty}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message id="textmessage" for="basket-qty" />
                </h:column>

                <h:column rendered="...">
                    <h:commandButton action="#{basket.addProduct(product)}"
                                     value ="Add to Basket">
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
```

Basically the problem is that `maximum="#{product.stock.qty}"` is evaluating to zero, therefore my range is 0-0?

product.stock.qty evaluates correctly elsewhere in the table.

Comment: See [Using validator with a variable attribute in ui:repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682196/using-validator-with-a-variable-attribute-in-uirepeat)

Comment: @JasperdeVries nice, but is there any way without omni faces? I'm not allowed to use 3rd party stuff (at least I understand where the problem is now though)

Comment: Well, OmniFaces is open source...

Comment: I would love to but it's a college project with no external frameworks or libraries allowed ..