# Using convertDateTime tag in DataTable component and every ajax requests re-creating Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean, date-conversion, ajax-request

I'm using convertDateTime tag in DataTable component. Connected managed bean property to timezone attribute. In this situation, every ajax requests re-creating Managed Bean.

The Managed Bean scope is View Scoped.

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputLabel value="Date"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.date}">
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{myBean.timezone}" locale="tr" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
    </h:outputText>
</h:column>




@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

   @PostConstruct
   public void initBeanMethod(){
      System.out.println("PostConstruct method is called...");
   }

   private TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();

   public TimeZone getTimezone() {
      return timezone;
   }

   public void setTimezone(TimeZone timezone) {
      this.timezone = timezone;
   }
```

Shows the following output after each ajax request: **"PostConstruct method is called..."**

Do you have an idea about Re-creation of beans on each request?

Note: I apologize for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will indeed happen when you bind attributes of tag handlers to a view scoped bean. This is related to JSF [issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) which is fixed for the upcoming JSF 2.2. In a nutshell, view scoped beans are stored in the view state. So when the view is to be restored, the view scoped beans are not available yet. But tag handlers (and `id` and `binding` attributes of JSF components) runs during building the view, so it will implicitly create a brand new view scoped bean instance. After restoring the view, those new view scoped bean instances will however be replaced by the ones in the view state. See also  [`@ViewScoped` fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers).

There are several ways to fix this particular problem, all are outlined in this answer: [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284) But in *your particular case* there's probably a much easier solution: you seem to want to use the system's default timezone in all datetime converters. You can also achieve this by just setting the following context parameter in `web.xml`:

```html
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC. Thank you for your enlightening response. I use the context parameter already, but this is not enough for accurate results. Your shared links going to read carefully. Thank you again...