# How to add validator (with disable condition) to primefaces datatable with cellEditor?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 2.2.1
and I want set `f:validatorLength` to one row in datatable with many rows with `p:cellEditor`.

```
<c:set var="flag" value="#{item.key eq 'someKey'}" />
<p:column headerText="header">
    <p:cellEditor>
       <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
            </f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{item.value}" style="width:100%" >
    <f:validateLength maximum="4" disabled="#{flag}"/>
                </p:inputText>

                </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

And when flag is `true` for chosen inputText with appropriate key, then validator turn on for all inputTexts. And when flag is `false` - validator turn on for all inputTexts. But I want set validator to some inputTexts and so on.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem. The attributes of `<f:validateXxx>` tags are evaluated during view build time. So they can't depend on a variable which is only available during view render time.

This is basically the same problem as outlined and answered in detail here: [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284)

In your particular case, apart from homegrowing a validator yourself which programmatically evaluates `#{item}` inside the `validate()` method, you could use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:validator>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) which enables render-time evaluation of all attributes.

```html
<p:inputText value="#{item.value}">
    <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.Length" maximum="4" disabled="#{flag}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm create my own validator. It works! And now I have another problem. I want to update (messages element with error) after clicking ('cancel') in cellEditor. How can I do it in PF 2.2.1? In 3.4 we have ajax event "rowEditCancel" and it must work, but what about in 2.2.1? Thank you!