# How to display a date in different patterns in JSF t:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, date

I have the next data table in my page:

```
<t:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfPersons}" var="current">
   <t:column>
      <t:outputText value="#{current.birthdate}">
         <f:converter pattern="dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm" type="date"/>
      </t:outputText>
   </t:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

`Person` is an object I created, and one of it's properties is birthdate.
Now I wish to display the details of many persons in this `<t:dateTable>`, including the birthdate. As you can see, I choose to display the birthdate in `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm` pattern, so I can see the time if known. Now, the problem is that some of the birthdates doesn't have a time (only date), and when the time is `null` in `java.util.Date`, the time is automatic 00:00. How can I display the birthdate in short pattern if time is unknown (only date), and the regular pattern when I know the time (date and time)?

What happens now:

```
17/3/1994 5:56
1/1/1991 00:00
12/2/1990 17:53
21/12/2012 00:00
```

What I want to see:

```
17/3/1994 5:56
1/1/1991
12/2/1990 17:53
21/12/2012
```

Short pattern when time is unknown.

---

This is what I'm writing in the page.xhtml:

```
<t:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
<f:converter convertetId="myconverter" pattern="[some pattern]" timeZone="America/Chicago" type="date">
</t:outputText>
```

This is the converter:

```
public class MyConverter extends DateTimeConverter
{
@Override
public String getAsString (FacesContext faces, UIComponent comp, Object obj)
{
this.setTimeZone(null);
String result = super.getAsString(faces, comp, obj);
// My converter here...
return result;
}

@Override
public void setTimeZone(TimeZone tz)
{
// Always setting my own time zone, no matter what.
super.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
}
}
```

Now, as you can see, I'm always setting the time zone myself on `getAsString` because
somehow now the f:converter doesn't recognize it's attributes... know why?

Comment: Just finished reading. You would need to implement a custom converter I think. I haven't worked with Java dates that much so I'm not sure if there's a pattern that already deals with your scenario. I'm going to bed (it's 4am) so if no one answers you I'll show you how to do it. You should get an answer quick though, that's an easy question...then again I'm know to make hasty judgments so I might be wrong lol.

Comment: What is the data type of current.birthdate ?

Comment: As Andy said, gooing with a custom converter is a good choice (And I think the best). Another ugly solution, would be to get the pattern from your Person objects: `<f:converter pattern="#{current.birthdayPattern}" type="date"/>` and in `getBirthdayPattern` you test on the date value

Comment: Thanks, Andy and Laabidi.
It seems I have to do a costum converter, but I don't know how to do this. Laabidi, I thought to do similiar solution as you suggested: to create a `getter` only for displaying, which I perform a check If I have a time or not, and return the date as string with the suitable pattern. But in the future I would have many objects with date, and I don't want to do this ugly solution in each object. So... How can I create a custom converter? Thanks. :)

Comment: erencan, `current.birthdate` is a `java.util.Date`, a property inside `Person` I've created (which is `current`).

Comment: for custom converter, take a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: You can extend `java.util.Date` to your own class and override `toString()` method to modify the printed date if you do not want to implement a converter.

Comment: Wow, it's sounds like a good idea, but I have many places I'm using date in my project, and I don't want to run over the project and change them all. Thanks :) Laabidi, I'm checking the link you gave me.

Comment: @Andy, didn't get what you mean

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi lol, sorry. Nice alternative. I never thought of using pattern that way.

Comment: ah, lol, it's the kind of lazy solutions, but using converters is much better (centralized solution)

Comment: Hi everyone,
I'm still working on the new converter.
You all gave me great solutions! Thank you all!
If I'll have issues, I hope you still be here :)

Comment: Hi everyone, I've finished the converter, and it seems to work fine. But when I tried to set the other properties in <f:converter> (like "type"/"pattern"/"timeZone", suddenly it doesn't familiar with this attributes. What I did is everytime when the f:converter fires the main method (`getAsString`), I'm setting the properties myself and it's working. But anyone know why f:converter suddenly don't recognize his attributes?

Comment: It could be anywhere so we might need to look at it. Show us the converter and how you are calling it from your xhtml. Off the top of my head I can't answer with seeing it because as far as I know that's not standard behavior

Comment: Are you doing something like this by any chance '<f:converter converterId="myConverter" pattern="somePattern" .../>'  cuz if you are that's wrong. You should be stacking them. Google add multiple converters in JSF or something. Its hard to use the comment section on a phone :/

Comment: @Andy Hi , I'm sorry for the silence in the few last days.
I'm updating the code right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable)

Comment: @BalusC thanks man, I see the problem there. But I have different issue: I don't have my own converter: I'm using `<f:converter converterId="myconverter">` and `f:converter` have more some attributes (pattern, type, timeZone...) and somehow it doesn't recognize the other attributes at all.

Comment: @user2542954 Still having issues ?! He basically gave you the answer. If you are using `converterId="myconverter"` then it's implied you are using a custom one written by you. Let me know if you solved it. I'll see what I can do

Comment: @user2542954 Let me know if you can't solve it still I mean. No use torturing yourself after almost a week. I'll help you out if you need me to.

Comment: @Andy Hi Andy and thank you all. You gave me the answer, and that's why I probably can't use the other attributes of the converter.
I solve the problem, as I said, by setting this attributes manually each row... Thats a nasty solution, but it's working... Thank you all again!

Comment: @user2542954 sure no problem. Good luck with everything

Answer (score 0):

Use [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library by ocpsoft. It has a nice [pre-built converter for JSF](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/#section-6), also with support for different Locales.