# Converter attribute of outputText set to bean property breaks ViewScope

Tags: jsf-2

Based on the third option/example provided in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7531284/944396 I tried to have a converter be a property in my ViewScoped bean; however, when I do so it breaks the view scope for that bean (it gets constructed multiple times when it should not be).

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if that example is assuming you are running a newer version of Mojarra that has fixed the ViewScope/binding issue. I myself am running Mojarra 2.1.6. Here is the bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private Double myVal; 
    private Converter converter;

    public void Bean() {
        converter = new MyCustomConverterClass();
    }

    public Converter getConverter() {
        return converter;
    }

    public Double getMyVal() {
        return myVal;
    }

    public void setMyVal(Double myVal) {
        this.myVal = myVal;
    }

}
```

And the usage:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.myVal}" converter="#{bean.converter}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it breaks the view scope. The `converter` attribute is evaluated during view build time. Apart from using other options listed in the answer you found [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284), you'd need to upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.1.18.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding. Just for more background, in my usage the converter for this field is dynamic. Since upgrading isn't an option at the moment, I will continue with my (less than ideal) workaround of just having two outputTexts (one for each converter) and then dynamically choosing which is rendered.