# Converter can't get rich:dataGrid rows as custom parameters

Tags: jsf, richfaces, converters, jsf-1.2, mojarra

I need a converter with custom parameters, I've made it and it works well, except when I use it with row elements and I can't understand why, ideas?

**Examples**

This works well:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"> 
    <cc:converter param="#{bean.attribute}" />
</h:outputText>
```

also this one:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"> 
    <cc:converter param="fixedValue" />
</h:outputText>
```

this one doesn't work at all, param is null inside the converter:

```
<rich:dataGrid value="#{bean.list}" var="row">
    <h:outputText value="#{row.value}"> 
        <cc:converter param="#{row.attribute}" />
    </h:outputText>
</rich:dataGrid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See BalusC link. It describes why your converter doesn't work. Converter without parameters works fine inside datatable in JSF 1.2. For simulate conversion you can use getter method in object which represents row like getConvertedValue and move your code from converter into this method. After that in datatable you can call #{row.convertedValue} for displaying the converted value.

Comment: The link posted by BalusC solved my problem, I used the "f:attribute way".