# f:convertNumber failing when currencySymbol is obtained from bean via EL

Tags: jsf, number-formatting

Hi in my project I need to visualize currency value, as far in my  f:convertNumber

I use a fixed  currencySymbol; everything is ok, but when I try to get the symbol with an expression language like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{rowItem.value}">
    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="#{rowItem.getCurrencySymbol()}" groupingUsed="true" maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
</h:outputText>
```

it is like the method getCurrencySymbol is not called, I am sure there is something I am missing.

Comment: Do you have any nested forms?

Comment: I have no problem using a dynamic currency symbol - append your namespaces for `h` and `f` and your code for the class behind the `rowItem` object please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will happen if `#{rowItem}` is only available during view render time, such as when it's specified by `<h:dataTable var="rowItem">`, as the variable name itself already suggests. It can also happen if `#{rowItem}` gets changed between building the view and rendering the view, such as when it's coming from a dropdown component in the same form. The `<f:convertNumber>` is namely a taghandler, not an UI component. It gets executed during view build time, not during view render time. The desired `#{rowItem}` value is not per definition available during view build time.

This all is explained in [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/) In that answer, you can substitute "JSTL" with `<f:convertNumber>` as they both are taghandlers and thus have exactly the same lifecycle.

There's no solution in standard JSF API without creating a custom converter and changing the view or model. You can find possible solutions in this answer: [How to set converter properties for each row/item of h:dataTable/ui:repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/)

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) offers [`<o:converter>`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/converter) out the box for exactly this problem. Use it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{rowItem.value}">
    <o:converter converterId="javax.faces.Number" currencySymbol="#{rowItem.getCurrencySymbol()}" type="currency" />
</h:outputText>
```

*(note that I omitted the other two properties as those are the default already when `type="currency"` is used)*